# Overriding onBack Pressed?

Tags: android

Correct me if i am wrong
"moveTaskToBack(false/true);" has nothing to do with the visibility of the Activity  ,but has everything to do with Activity Stack,because many times on stackoverflow i find people being confused on this.

Now My Scenario:
there are two activites A and B
A is the root Activity
B is launched from activity A

the thing is **i don't want my activity B to be killed** after the back button is pressed,(just i want it to be invisible,and activity A to be visible which will happen on its own )so that i can restore its state afterwards.

so after searching a bit i came to know about 
moveTaskToBack(false);,
which seemed to be the solution as it does not kill the activity (because the activity is not sent to back in the activity stack),but the only problem is.it works with Root Activity,and hence it will not work in my case.So is there any alternative which i can use with"non-root" activities,so that the state of Activity is restored....

Comment: yes you misunderstood movetobackstack. It moves the task containing activity to the back of the activity stack. and as far as making activity invisivle you have misunderstood the lifecycle and how tasks and back stack work http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: @thank you that was a much better answer ....put your comment in as the answer so that i can accapt it nd give it a plus 1

Comment: so on back press activity gets destroyed. save your values in `onPause` and restore it `onResume`. To store values you can check storage options in android http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.

Comment: But my situation is complex-ed .Activity A is sending Activity b some data to start with,that data is a list.so after some time data may change.

here is my scenario 
activity a generates a list of all songs.i press on a particular song.Activity B receives that Data and plays the song say first song,after song1 is completed song2 is played,now i press back button?song2's current position and details are saved,and now i go back to the activity a and play a different song,what will happen then??will not   song 2 will be played,??or can i handle this with some method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41346/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user2993677)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have misunderstood

`public boolean moveTaskToBack (boolean nonRoot)`

Added in API level 1

**Move the task containing this activity to the back of the activity stack. The activity's order within the task is unchanged.**

Parameters

**nonRoot   If false then this only works if the activity is the root of a task; if true it will work for any activity in a task.**

Returns

If the task was moved (or it was already at the back) true is returned, else false.

Back Button by default takes you back to the previous activity. It pop's the activity from the back stack and the previous activity in the stack takes focus.

Save the state of the activity in `onPause` restore it in `onCreate` or `onResume`. To store values persistently chekc the below link for storage options.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

You may want to check the answer by commonsware in the below link.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/4Pz6LrzVpx0

Comment: Can you help me here???http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104340/unable-to-display-album-art?